# Primefaces selectOneButton: onchange - get selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I need to use the selected value selectOneButton in a js method - called on onchange event.

```
<p:selectOneButton id="sex" value="#{MyBean.profile.gender}" onchange="onChangeGender(this.value);">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Female"  itemValue="female"/></p:selectOneButton>
```

My js method is onChangeGender(gender) , where gender must be the selected value.

I prefer not to make a request.

My Primefaces version is 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `this.value` to `onChangeGender`, try passing `event.target.value`.